# How can we translate classical SNR into the quantum world?

Tags: error-correction

I am using a LDPC codes to correct error encountered in the quantum world. In the LDPC package in python the one of the parameter is SNR. I would like to explore the possibility if I can translate this parameter into something and then I can apply errors to the qubits.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the python package but SNR is a measure of noise in AWGN channel. The BSC channel is more relevant to working with LDPC in QECC. Most LDPC decoder can work with either channel (with proper adjustments for LLR calculations...)

Comment: @unknown: https://hichamjanati.github.io/pyldpc/ this is the package that  I am using. And snr parameter here is a must.

Comment: it looks like this decoder is designed for AWGN channel...you're better off finding a better package that can handle BSC channel. The difference in the decoding algorithm is not that big but it's not trivial. Even after you have an LDPC decoder for BSC; this can only be used for CSS codes so you decode $X$ and $Z$ part independently; this is only possible for some quantum channels. Also in QECC the input to the decoder has to be the syndrome not the actual received data as in the classical case...bottom line : there are a lot of complications to consider here